# What does s permission means?

Tags: command-line

While i run `ls -l` command on `/usr/bin/sudo`, it shows

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 121144 Feb 28  2013 /usr/bin/sudo
```

What does the `s` permission means for this `sudo` file?

Comment: @rusty you can be able to revert back the close vote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`s`(setuid) means set user ID upon execution. If setuid bit turned on a file, user executing that executable file gets the permissions of the individual or group that owns the file.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 121144 Feb 28  2013 /usr/bin/sudo
```

In this `s` permission was given  to  owner, so it represents the file is executable and set-user-ID mode is set.

**[Source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-bsd-linux-setuid-file/)**